# Angular material like Textbox label overlap the input data

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I am using [this](http://learning.aws.ipv4.ro/html/login.html) learning management system template by themeforest . When I am using the input textbox field and filling the data and tab to next field the label overlap the data filled in texbox .

[image]

I have created [this](http://goo.gl/H4DqSa) sample demo project to see the demo which include the only required css files used in textbox.
Need help in solving that.

Comment: The plunkr you added works fine. There is no overlap there.

Comment: Try to fill complete then see